# php loop through each string line in textarea

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I am using this script to get every line from a textarea in an array:

```
//trim off excess whitespace off the whole
$text = trim(get_field('backlinks'));

//explode all separate lines into an array
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);

//trim all lines contained in the array.
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

//loop through the lines
var_dump($textAr);
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    echo $line; 
}
```

My output from `var_dump` is:

```
 array(3) { [0]=> string(29) "
 http://www.nasa.gov/
 " [1]=> string(25) "http://www.cnn.com/
 " [2]=> string(27) "http://www.twitter.com/

 " }
```

My html output from the `echo $line;` is:

```
http://www.nasa.gov/<br>
http://www.cnn.com/<br>
http://www.twitter.com/
```

My script handles it wrong. I need the output of `echo $line;` to be:

```
http://www.nasa.gov/http://www.cnn.com/http://www.twitter.com/
```

And the output of my `var_dump` to be:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(29) "http://www.nasa.gov/" [1]=> string(25) "http://www.cnn.com/" [2]=> string(27) "http://www.twitter.com/" }
```

I don't want the line breaks in my output/echo. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you have in $text variable? It seems you have some br tags in there

Comment: You’re likely not taking into account that a line break can be represented by more than a single \n, but can have an additional \r as well. (Or _only_ an \r, on some [older] systems.)

Answer (score 1):

```
//trim off excess whitespace off the whole
$text = trim(get_field('backlinks'));
//explode all separate lines into an array
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
//trim all lines contained in the array.
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');
//loop through the lines
var_dump($textAr);
foreach($textAr as $line) {
    echo str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\r","",$line)); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using impload.

echo implode(",",$textAr) ;

Answer (score -1):

i'm sorry, i was thinking it was the PHP code, it was a setting of my textarea where its ad a 
     < br >
 after every line.